# C++ wrap C struct *and* and functions

Tags: c++, c, struct

I'm trying to wrap a C library which uses patterns like this:

```
Thing* x= new_thing_("blah");
Thing* tmp= thing_copy(x);
free_thing(tmp);
Other* y=get_other(x,7);
char* message=get_message(x,y);
free_thing(x);
free_other(y);
```

In c++, I'd like to be able to do something like

```
auto_ptr<CXXThing> x=new CXXThing("blah");
auto_ptr<CXXThing> tmp=new CXXThing(*x);
auto_ptr<CXXOther> y=x->get_other(7);
char* message = y->get_message();
```

Obviously, CXXOther wraps a pointer to a CXXThing as well.  So the problem I'm encountering is that essentially I'd like to just "insert" functions and members into existing structs (I think this is known as the "Mixin" idea).

The problem is that if I include a Thing as an element of the CXXThing, then I don't know how I'd declare the constructor, and if I include a *pointer* to the wrapped class, then I have an extra level of useless indirection.

How should I wrap it so that this is possible?  (An answer of "What you want to do is not best/possible... here is the proper way" is also acceptable.)

Comment: I may be wrong, but I was under the impression that you might return auto_ptrs to express transferring the ownership of an object (http://www.gotw.ca/publications/using_auto_ptr_effectively.htm)

Comment: That is entirely correct. However, for the above situation it is simpler to wrap `Thing` and `Other` into their own classes, and results in classes that are easier to use by the user.

Answer (score 9):

Instead of using `auto_ptr`s, you can use the RAII idiom more directly. Here's one way you can do it:

A `CXXThing` class that wraps a `Thing`:

```
class CXXThing
{
public:
    // Acquire a Thing
    explicit CXXThing(const char* str) : x(::new_thing_(str)) {}
    // Copy a Thing
    CXXThing(const CXXThing& rhs) : x(::thing_copy(rhs.x)) {}
    // Copy-and-swap idiom
    CXXThing& operator=(CXXThing rhs)
    {
        swap(*this, rhs);
        return *this;
    }
    // Release a Thing
    ~CXXThing() { ::free_thing(x); }

    friend void swap(CXXThing& lhs, CXXThing& rhs)
    {
        Thing* tmp = lhs.x;
        lhs.x = rhs.x;
        rhs.x = tmp;
    }

private:
    Thing* x;
    friend class CXXOther;
};
```

A `CXXOther` class that wraps an `Other`:

```
class CXXOther
{
public:
    // Acquire an Other
    explicit CXXOther(CXXThing& thing, int i) : y(::get_other(thing.x, i)) {}
    // Release an Other
    ~CXXOther() { ::free_other(y); }
    // Get a message
    char* get_message(const CXXThing& x) { return ::get_message(x.x, y); }
private:
    // Instaces of Other are not copyable.
    CXXOther(const CXXOther& rhs);
    CXXOther& operator=(const CXXOther& rhs);
    Other* y; 
};
```

Translating your C code into C++ code with the above classes:

```
int main()
{
    CXXThing x("blah");

    {
        CXXThing tmp = x;
    } // tmp will go away here.

    CXXOther y(x, 7);
    char* msg = y.get_message(x);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is the extra level of indirection necessary?

Comment: Well, the class is wrapping a C-style interface to provide a C++ interface, so yes the extra indirection is necessary. But the code I have has only one level of indirection, while the second code snippet in your question has two: the `auto_ptr<CXXThing>` and `CXXThing` wrapping a `Thing*`.

Comment: Consider `using std::swap; swap(lhs.x, rhs.x);` in your friend swap which is more concise, one line shorter.

Comment: But this doesn't work, because some of the pointers returned by these functions are *shared*, and not RAII.  so I need to be able to sometimes use auto_ptr and sometimes not.

Comment: @Jeremy Salwen: Then use [Boost's `shared_ptr`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm). If the user needs shared semantics, let them use `boost::shared_ptr<CXXThing>` and `boost::shared_ptr<CXXOther>`. If they don't, they can just use `CXXThing` and `CXXOther` by themselves.